# Prevent logo stretching in a navbar-brand on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a [`navbar-brand` with a logo and button](http://www.atapgogreen.com) and they stretch out when viewed on an iPhone while the menu is collapsed.

How can I prevent this?

```
<header id="header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                <div class="slogan"><p>  PERTAMA DI INDONESIA : </p><div class="slogs">Dengan Formula Plastik Baja</div><p></p></div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="works.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">OUR PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->
</header>
```

Comment: I didn't find any stretch, can you post an image how it looks like?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/sx4qma689/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add class="img-responsive" to img.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
</a>
```